# Mix array values with all possbile other values of an other Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array and want to mix all values of the first array (21) with all other array offsets:

```
$option_variations = array(

'21' => array(
            'standard_options' => array(81, 82, 80, 79),
        ),

'19' => array(
            'standard_options' => array(77, 71, 70, 69,90,72,91,73),
        ),


'2' => array(
            'pso_options' => array(8),
        ),

);
```

I found a sampling method in another post that mixed all possible values, but that's not what I need.

```
    $new_array = array();

    foreach($option_variations as $option_id => $option_arrays){
        foreach($option_arrays as $option => $option_array){


        }

        /*
        foreach($result_data as $option => $option_id){     
            $new_array[$option][] = $option_id;
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: Result should look like:

[0]
   {
    [standard_option]
     {
      [0] => 81
      [1] => 77
     }
     
    [pso_option]
     {
      [0] => 8
     } 
   }

[1]
   {
    [standard_option]
     {
      [0] => 81
      [1] => 71
     }
     
    [pso_option]
     {
      [0] => 8
     } 
   }

[2]
   {
    [standard_option]
     {
      [0] => 81
      [1] => 70
     }
     
    [pso_option]
     {
      [0] => 8
     } 
   }

Comment: Will you be okay if there is multiple foreach of for loops?

Comment: would be okay, yes